# mod_rewrite help for php to html redirect, html to php intern, and support subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to always show .html in the address bar. All .php requests to be redirected to a .html in the address bar. And .html requests to show the .php file.

I have set up my webhoster with following domain and subdomains

```
www.example.com => /
test1.example.com => /test1
test2.example.com = /test2
```

Then I setup .htaccess in the root directory as

```
RewriteEngine on

# Externally redirect .php requests to .html
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1.html [R=302,L]

# Internally redirect .html requests to .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.+).htm$ $1.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

This works great

```
www.example.com => /index.php
www.example.com/abc/def/test.php => /abc/def/test.php - Address bar shows "www.example.com/abc/def/test.html"
www.example.com/abc/def/test.html => /abc/def/test.php
```

but not for the subdomain

```
test1.example.com => /test1/index.php
test1.example.com/abc/def/test.html => /test1/abc/def/test.php
(!!) test1.example.com/abc/def/test.php => 404 - Address bar shows "test1.example.com/test1/abc/def/test.html"
```

For some reason test1 shows double. What lines do I need to change/add in the htaccess?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are linking to the `.html` URL in your pages? (ie. You are not relying on the redirect to replace the `.php` extension on all requests?) And the `/test1` subdirectory is the DocumentRoot of the subdomain, you don't have additional directives that rewrite the request (simulating a document root directory)?

Comment: I am guessing your subdomains are not set up as individual VHosts to begin with, but this is probably a rewrite implemented at the level of the one virtual host they share with the main domain. Looks like `ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS` is still empty though, otherwise that external redirect should not happen in the first place. And because of the subdomain rewrite on an upper level, the path already starts with `test1/` or `test2/` here. Try and discard that part, if it is present: `RewriteRule ^(?:test[12]/)?(.+)\.php$ /$1.html [R=302,L]`